# SUM the result of a for LOOP java

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, sum

So, I made a for loop with static and was working fine. But then I wanted to SUM the values of this loop to get the total value. But everytime I try to print it, I get the value 0. Any ideas? Please excuse the primitive coding.

I also have a **Console class** that I don't post but its from the **Scanner** class and is used for the "userInput".

Main class:

```java
public class Main {

    private static Console Consola;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ItemPower oco = new ItemPower();
        CalculateThings oco2 = new CalculateThings();


        System.out.println(Math.ceil(oco.preçoUnitarioVIII_II));

        double unitariaT5 = Consola.userInput("Qual o Preço unitario da T5?");
        double unitariaT4 = Consola.userInput("Qual o Preço unitario da T4?");
        double unitariaCedarLog = Consola.userInput("Qual o Preço unitario da chedar Log?");
        double desejadaT5 = Consola.userInput("Qual o Preço desejada de T5?");




        System.out.println("Investimento em tier 5 Plank é de: " + oco2.tier5Plank(unitariaT5, desejadaT5));
        System.out.println("Investimento em tier 4 Plank é de: " + oco2.tier4Plank(desejadaT5, unitariaT4));
        System.out.println("Investimento em Chedar logs é de: " + oco2.chedarLog(desejadaT5, unitariaCedarLog));

        System.out.println("value of totaT5 is " +oco2.totalT5);

        CalculateThings.loopT5();
            }
    
}
```

Class Calculate Things:

```java
public class CalculateThings {

     double unitariaT5;
     double unitariaT4;
     double unitariaCedarLog;
     double desejadaT5;
     double totalT5 = 0;
     double totalT4 = 0;
     double totalCH = 0;



    public double tier5Plank(double desejadaT5, double unitariaT5){
     return desejadaT5 *  unitariaT5;

    }

    public double tier4Plank(double desejadaT5, double unitariaT4){

        return desejadaT5 *  unitariaT4;
    }

    public double chedarLog(double desejadaT5, double unitariaCedarLog){


        return desejadaT5 *  unitariaCedarLog * 3;
    }


    public double loopT5(double desejadaT5) {

        for (int i = (int) desejadaT5; i >= 1; i = (int) (i * 0.367)) {
            totalT5 += i;
                      
        }
        return totalT5;
    }

}
```

Thanks again for the help.

Comment: This won't compile because when you call the `loopT5()` method you don't pass any value. Other than that, `i` in your loop shouldn't be an int in this case. You lose precision when converting from double to int.

Comment: Also, you seem to be printing the result before calculating it?

Comment: @Amongalen what value should i put inside then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to replace these two lines as below.

```
System.out.println("value of totaT5 is " +oco2.totalT5);
CalculateThings.loopT5();
```

With below two lines.

```
oco2.loopT5();
System.out.println("value of totaT5 is " +oco2.totalT5);
```

For below code, i am able to get require output

```
class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        CalculateThings oco2 = new CalculateThings();


        double unitariaT5 = 5;
        double unitariaT4 = 4;
        double unitariaCedarLog = 10;
        double desejadaT5 = 15;


        System.out.println("Investimento em tier 5 Plank é de: " + oco2.tier5Plank(unitariaT5, desejadaT5));
        System.out.println("Investimento em tier 4 Plank é de: " + oco2.tier4Plank(desejadaT5, unitariaT4));
        System.out.println("Investimento em Chedar logs é de: " + oco2.chedarLog(desejadaT5, unitariaCedarLog));
        oco2.loopT5(5);
        System.out.println("value of totaT5 is " + oco2.totalT5);

    }

}
```

---

```
Output:

Investimento em tier 5 Plank é de: 75.0
Investimento em tier 4 Plank é de: 60.0
Investimento em Chedar logs é de: 450.0
value of totaT5 is 6.0
```

Comment: Thanks Sagar! that solved the issue. Man i feel dumb asking the computer to give me something before even asking him to run the for loop... Thanks very much!

Answer (score 3):

There are mainly 2 issues that I see here in the code attached.

First, you are not calling the `loopT5()` method with parameter. Also if you have already have instnace `oco2` of CalculateThings, you can call the method like this

```
oco2.loopT5(desejadaT5);
```

or else you can do it like this

```
double d = new CalculateThings().loopT5(desejadaT5);
System.out.println("value of totaT5 is " +d);
```

Second, print statement should be after calling the `loopT5()`.